# Get Features from ifeatureclass

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects

I am facing the issue while I am trying to get all the features back in 'Attribute Table'. 
What I am doing is.

1. Selected the layer from Map
2. Performs my Edits on few features (changing filed values)

(After I perform my changes I take

3. While I again want to get all my features back I am getting error.

**Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004151C**

I tried with below code :

In both the case it's giving error.

```
///////1st//////////

IFeatureClass pFc = ilayer.FeatureClass;
IFeatureCursor pFCursor;
IFeature pF;

queryFilterlast.WhereClause = "SHAPE.LEN IS NOT NULL";
pFCursor = pFc.Search(queryFilterlast, false);
pF = pFCursor.NextFeature();

while (pF != null)
{
   pF = pFCursor.NextFeature();
}

/////////2nd//////////////

//initialize queryfilter
                queryFilterlast.SubFields = "*";
                queryFilterlast.WhereClause = "SHAPE.LEN IS NOT NULL";


                //Using a query filter to search a feature class:
                featureselectionlast.SelectFeatures(queryFilterlast, esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, false);

                //output features assign into featureset
                featuresetlast = featureselectionlast.SelectionSet;

                if (featuresetlast.Count != 0)
                {
                    featuresetlast.Search(null, false, out icursor);
                    //featureCursor = icursor as IFeatureCursor;
                    IFeatureCursor featureCursorL = icursor as IFeatureCursor;

                    //Get the output features 
                    IFeature feature = featureCursorL.NextFeature();

                    //Loop through output features
                    while (feature != null)
                    {
                        feature = featureCursorL.NextFeature();
                    }
                    //Release the cursor
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(featureCursorL);
                    featureCursorL = null;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your error message is 'FDO_E_SE_NO_PERMISSIONS'.. [read more about ArcObjects Error Codes here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjectsonline/componenthelp/esricore/fdoerror.htm) and [a post about it here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=2&f=59&t=156685) for what that's worth. This is an SDE error, ensure your credentials are valid for querying/editing that table.

If your data is versioned you need to bracket **all modifications in an edit operation** during an edit session.. so it might be necessary to either disable the tool until the user has started editing or start/stop editing within the tool itself.

To check if the session is editing use the [IEditor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000qs000000) interface:

```
IEditor m_editor = app.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor") as IEditor;
if (m_editor.EditState == esriEditState.esriStateEditing) 
{
    m_editor.StartOperation();
    // do your operation
    m_editor.StopOperation("Your undo text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your where clause.

Here's an example that will get all you features in your feature class then test the geometry.

```
            IFeatureLayer ilayer = (IFeatureLayer)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.get_Layer(0);

            IQueryFilter queryFilterlast = new QueryFilterClass();

            IFeatureClass pFc = ilayer.FeatureClass;
            IFeatureCursor pFCursor;
            IFeature pF;

            queryFilterlast.WhereClause = null;
            pFCursor = pFc.Search(queryFilterlast, false);
            pF = pFCursor.NextFeature();

            while (pF != null && pF.Shape != null && pF.Shape.IsEmpty == false ) {
                if (pFc.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryLine || pFc.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline) {
                    ICurve curveForLength = (ICurve)pF.Shape;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(curveForLength.Length.ToString());

                }
                pF = pFCursor.NextFeature();
            }
```

Using the null query filter will return all of the features in your featureclass.  You can then test the shape field for a value , then get the value for length using the ICurve interface.

ESRI has a similar vba example here:
http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/19145